# Python Range Step Increasing

Tags: python, range

Is it possible to increase each step in range? Something like this:

```
    for num in range(1, 40, i++) :
       print(i)
...
1
2
3
4
...
```

Or step in range has only fixed size?

Comment: No, the example has step of increased size: range(1, 40, 1) -> range (1, 40, 2) -> etc.

Comment: A `while` loop will keep things simpler

Answer (score 2):

Yes, step in range has fixed size.

Something like this gives the output you want.

```
>>> j=0
>>> for i in xrange(1,40):
    j+=i
    print j
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you want an increasing step size with each iteration?

The code below does this

```
>>> for i in (i+sum(range(i)) for i in (range (1,10))):
...  print i
...
1
3
6
10
15
21
28
36
45
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

A `while` loop will result in cleaner code:

```
step = 1
i = 1
while i < 40:
    print i, step
    i += step
    step +=1
```

result:

```
1 1
2 2
4 3
7 4
11 5
16 6
22 7
29 8
37 9
```

Answer (score 1):

Using For loop

```
j = 0
for i in range(1,22):
    j += i
    if j <= 22:
        print(j, end=" ")
```

Output:
1 3 6 10 15 21

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).